# JSONP not being fetched by browser on Android 2.2.2 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, jsonp

I have run into a strange problem on **Android**, using **jQuery mobile** and **Phonegap**.

I am making **JSONP** requests to our server to fetch each pages content. The application works fine for a while and then suddenly the requests **timeout**. Using Weinre I am able to inspect the dom while the application is running on my device and can actually see the script tags being appended to the head by jQuery.

What is strange is that when I tail my Apache logs **on the server I don't see the request coming through** for the ones which timeout as If the browser doesn't send the request?

This all works fine in the browser and on different versions of Android.

Could it be a memory issue?

I am using `jQuery Mobile 1.1rc1 + Phonegap 1.5.0 + jQuery 1.7.1`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with Phonegap 1.5, rolling back to 1.4 fixes the issue

Comment: Is this issue logged with PhoneGap ?