# phonegap application chrashes after two json requests on Android

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, getjson

i'm developing a phonegap (v 1.5 Cordova) app with jquery mobile (1.1.0-RC1) and jquery 1.7.1.

I make two  json requests on button click to update my database.
the first one works well:

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://mydomain/api.php"+last_update,

  function (data) {
    var $page = $( search_result );
  var  $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" );
  var output;

        updates = data;
        db.transaction(auswertung,db_error);


});
```

the second one stops working on several android devices after two calls.
Either the success function nor the error function is called. Only a Sntp timeout error shows up:

> SntpClient(75): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

and the application crashes.

```
    var url = "http://mydomain/api.php"+filter; //filter: adds some get-parameters to it
console.log(url);
$.getJSON(
  url,
  function (data) {

            var $page = $( search_result );
        var  $content = $page.children( ":jqmData(role=content)" );
        var output;

        if(data.length==0){
        output ="<p>no results!"+"</p>";
        }else{
        output = "<ul name=\"results\" data-role=\"listview\" data-theme=\"g\">";
    $.each(data,function(key,val){  

    output +="<li>"+val.Name+"</li>";
    });
        output +="</ul>";
        }
     $content.html(output);
     $page.page();
  $('#results').listview('refresh');
$.mobile.changePage( $page ,{dataUrl: "#search_result"});
}).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {         alert("Verbindungsfehler"); 
    console.log("error " + textStatus);
    console.log("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
})
```

Comment: The SntpClient error is a red herring so you are safe to ignore it.

Comment: The hole application crashes when this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same problem. The first request is successful and subsequent ones fail.

We fixed this by downgrading phonegap from 1.5 to 1.4.1

This seems to be a bug in Phonegap 1.5. There are no bug reports for it as far as I can tell, and it's quite difficult to reproduce without sharing the entire codebase.

The second request seems to timeout after 30 seconds no matter what you do.

We fought this for days. The only solution right now is to roll-back to Phonegap 1.4.1

Here is my bro's question [on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837449/jsonp-not-being-fetched-by-browser-on-android-2-2-2-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

`Address family not supported by protocol` I believe means that the device does not know what to do with a URL that starts with `...`.

What are you trying to accomplish by using `...`?

Comment: "..." is just a placeholder. I edited it before I asked the question.

Comment: @user1294028 Well what URLs are you actually using? Because the error message states that your URL is invalid and that it doesn't understand the protocol (i.e. `http`/`https`/`file`, etc.).

Comment: I'm using `http://mydomain/api.php`. `+filter` adds some get-parameters to it. This works well twice. But if you hit the button for the second function a third time, the application crashes.